# TicTacToe in C++ (Gandalf vs Saruman)

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I've written a TicTacToe game using classes, just for learning purposes...
and I wonder If this code can be improved.

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "tictactoe.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Tictactoe game;
    game.intro();
    return 0;
}
```

## tictactoe.hpp

```
#ifndef tictactoe_hpp
#define tictactoe_hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Tictactoe {
public:
    // Constructor and Destructor
    Tictactoe();
    ~Tictactoe();

    // Functions
    int placeToken(int, int, int);
    bool checkHorizontal(int);
    bool checkVertical(int);
    bool checkDiagonal(int);
    bool playerWon(int);
    bool positionIsTaken(int, int);
    bool isTie();

    void intro();
    void gamePlay();
    void showBoard();

private:
    // Variables
    int board[3][3], pos[2], turn;
    bool gameOver;
};

#endif /* tictactoe_hpp */
```

## tictactoe.cpp

```
#include "tictactoe.hpp"


class Tictactoe::Tictactoe {
    // Board for tictactoe
    int board[3][3] = {
        {0,0,0},
        {0,0,0},
        {0,0,0}
    };
    // Gandalf begins
    int turn = 1;
    // Get place position on board from user
    int pos[2] = {0,0};
    // for the gamePlay loop
    bool gameOver = false;
};

Tictactoe::Tictactoe() {};
Tictactoe::~Tictactoe() {};

// Function to place user token on given position
int Tictactoe::placeToken(int y, int x, int token){
    board[y][x] = token;
    return 0;
}

// Checking if the given position is already taken or not.
bool Tictactoe::positionIsTaken(int y, int x){
    if(board[y][x] == 0){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

// Check if player won horizontally
bool Tictactoe::checkHorizontal(int token){
    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        if( (board[i][0] == token) && (board[i][1] == token) && (board[i][2] == token) ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Check if player won vertically
bool Tictactoe::checkVertical(int token){
    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        if ((board[0][i] == token) && (board[1][i] == token) && (board[2][i] == token)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


// Check if player won diagonally
bool Tictactoe::checkDiagonal(int token) {
    if((board[0][2] == token) && (board[1][1] == token) && (board[2][0] == token)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool Tictactoe::playerWon(int token){
    return checkDiagonal(token) || checkVertical(token) || checkHorizontal(token);
}

bool Tictactoe::isTie(){
    for(int row = 0;row <= 2; row++){
        for(int col = 0;col <= 2; col++){
            if(board[row][col] == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// for printing board
void Tictactoe::showBoard(){
    cout << "\t-----------------\n";
    for(int row = 0;row <= 2; row++){
        for(int col = 0;col <= 2; col++){
            cout << "\t" << board[row][col] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\t-----------------\n";
};

void Tictactoe::gamePlay(){
    while(!gameOver){
        cout << ((turn == 1) ? "\t#############\n\tGandalf's Turn\n\t#############":"\t#############\n\tSaruman's Turn\n\t#############") << endl;
        if(turn == 1){

            // get User input
            cout << "Place Token (i.e: 0 2): ";
            cin >> pos[0] >> pos[1];

            // Ask for new input if position is already taken
            while(positionIsTaken(pos[0], pos[1])) {
                cout << "Position is taken, try again..." << endl;
                cout << "Place Token (i.e: 0 2): ";
                cin >> pos[0] >> pos[1];
            }

            // Set token on given position
            board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 1;
            showBoard();
            // If player won horizontally
            if(isTie()){
                cout << "HA! Losers!" << endl;
                gameOver = true;
            }

            if(playerWon(1)){
                cout << "Gandalf Won." << endl;
                gameOver = true;
            }
            turn = 0;

        } else {
            // get User input
            cout << "Place Token (i.e: 0 2): ";
            cin >> pos[0] >> pos[1];

            // Ask for new input if position is already taken
            while(positionIsTaken(pos[0], pos[1])) {
                cout << "Position is taken, try again..." << endl;
                cout << "Place Token (i.e: 0 2): ";
                cin >> pos[0] >> pos[1];
            }

            // Set token on given position
            board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 2;
            showBoard();
            if(isTie()){
                cout << "HA! Losers!" << endl;
                gameOver = true;
            }
            // If player won horizontally
            if(playerWon(2)){
                cout << "Saruman Won." << endl;
                gameOver = true;
            }
            turn = 1;
        }
    }
}

void Tictactoe::intro(){
    char isReady;
    cout << "\t##################################\n\t# Welcome to the TicTacToe Game! #\n\t##################################" <<
    "\nPlayer 1 (Gandalf)\nPlayer 2 (Saruman)\n\nAre you ready to begin?" << endl;
    cin >> isReady;
    if(isReady == 'Y' || isReady == 'y'){
        gamePlay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Naming:**

- I would rename the intro function to 'run' or 'play' as it runs or plays the game, not just the intro.
- showBoard -> printBoard and delete the comment

**Misc.**

1) Instead of

```
bool Tictactoe::positionIsTaken(int y, int x){
    if(board[y][x] == 0){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You could just return the result directly:

```
bool Tictactoe::positionIsTaken(int y, int x){
    return board[y][x] != 0;
}
```

2) To ensure that a user does not for example input -5000 or 1000 in placeToken i would change the board data-type to an enum to store the state of each square on the board:

```
enum SquareStatus { Empty, Cross, Circle };
```

3) placeReturn should properly return void or an bool if the move was succesful instead of always just returning 0.

4) I would add a constructor argument containing the size of the game-board, making it possible to use a different sized board. This would also require the win calculation to change to be dynamic.

5) It looks like you're only checking one diagonal

6) There's a lot of duplicated code in the gamePlay